# From where does the service ID come from when using PrivateTmp=true in services?

Tags: systemd, services, tmp

Configuring a systemd service with `PrivateTmp=true` leads to the fact that the service uses a private `tmp` directory. Instead of `/tmp` such a service will use a directory like that:

```
/tmp/systemd-private-94ebb0a353a34259b6c794fe503c35f8-colord.service-Rb11Zg/tmp
```

While `94ebb0a353a34259b6c794fe503c35f8` is the boot ID (`/proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id`), what is the six characters long ID after `service-`? In which file is it stored?

Comment: That random string of 6 character looks very much like the suffix that `mkdtemp()` adds to make a unique temporary name, so I'd assume that's exactly what it is. I'll check the systemd source and post an answer if my suspicion is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The six random characters at the end of the systemd-private directory name are only there to guarantee that the directory name is unique and doesn't conflict with any existing directories when it is created. As of systemd v245, this is set up in `setup_one_tmp_dir()` in `src/core/namespace.c`. That function calls `mkdtemp()` to create a unique temporary directory, and `mkdtemp()` generates the random suffix to guarantee uniqueness.

I haven't found a way to extract the current temporary directory path for a given unit directly from systemd, but if you really need it, you can get that information in these two steps:

- Run `systemctl show some.service -p MainPID` and extract the PID (or obtain the PID of any one process in the unit in some other way)
- Search `/proc/ThePID/mountinfo` for the mount you're interested in (`/tmp` or `/var/tmp`) and extract the path from there.

Note that you only need to do this if there's more than one systemd-private directory for a machine-unit combination present. That is in itself a rare occurence, because systemd removes these directories for units that stop running for any reason. Of course, someone could go and create a systemd-private directory to confuse you, so don't just do `systemd-private-$bootID-some.service-*` when security is a concern.